# Greedy: 1.01 adds up to 4 coins but 1.02 reaches 5

Tags: c

I saw below and those are great examples to use as a guide.  I tried borrowing from both do my own thing, even though it probably isn't as efficient as those.  Why does input 1.01 return 4 coins but 1.02 returns the proper 5?  2.01 = 8 and 2.02 = 9?  Am I not accounting for a start of 0 as 1 in the coin_count??

```
int main(void)
{
    int q = 25;
    int d = 10;
    int n = 5;
    int p = 1;
    int balance = 0;
    int coin_count = 0;

    float change;
        do  {
            printf("Ciao!  How much change is owed?\n");
            printf("Enter amount in this format:  up to 999.99\n");
            change = get_float();
            }   
            while (change < 0);

        {
            balance = (int)(change * 100.0);
            printf ("Balance: %.2f\n", change);
        }
```

> I think the problem might be somewhere below with my while loops?

```
    while (balance >= q)
        {
            balance -= q;
            coin_count++;
        }   

    while (change >= d)
        {
            balance -= d;
            coin_count++;
        } 

    while (balance >= n)
        {
            balance -= n;
            coin_count++;
        }

    while (balance >= p)
        {
            balance -= p;
            coin_count++;
        }       

    printf ("Total amount of coins returned: %i\n", coin_count);


return 0;

}
```

Comment: I do not understand what this means "I saw below and those are great examples to use as a guide". Is this your code? What examples are you referring to?

Comment: I haven't tried to run your code, but **all** the answers you report are wrong by one. Returning 5 coins for a balance of 1.02 is not the proper answer as you write. So I am not sure if this code follows the guidelines for this site, as you know it to have errors and you are asking about these errors. This is better suited for stackoverflow.

Comment: There is a similar question with comments on this site when I searched, so "below" was regarding that one which was where I thought my post was going.  I am taking the CS50 online course from Edx.org  so, we have various other students that are on here, too.

Comment: I'll be sure to review the proper way to post on here.  I am only asking for hints and not answers--not trying to do anything wrong or violate any Stack rules.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be homework for Harvard's CS50. greedy.c refers to an exercise there. I will give you an outline (but not complete answers) for you to work with.

The error-by-one you see comes from the imperfect calculations with floats. Check to see that `1.01 *100.0` returns `10.999999`. Taking the int of this returns `100`. Think about ways to achieve the right result.

Code review comments on the code provided:

- Use proper indentation. For example the `do` statement does not need
  to be indented.
- Watch out for unneeded braces and in general be consistent with
  braces use. For example the balance calculation and printing do not
  need to be in braces. A example of inconsistency: you use a `{` on
  the same line with `do`, but on a different line with `while`.
- Use the standard c library functions to ask for input when you can. To
  ask for a float you could use `scanf("%f", &change);` Is there a reason to use an external function (which, by the way, is not defined here)
- Do proper input checking. What would happen if someone gave you the input
  213445505.87? What would happen if someone gave you the input 0.9956? The program would work but it goes against your stated accepted input.
- It is pretty inefficient to subtract the coins one by one in
  successive while loops. How would you solve the problem in your head,
  if you had to? Think about how you can get rid of these while loops.

Comment: Thanks so much for a very helpful answer!  Yes.  I fond another CS50 question on here regarding the same exercise, so I thought it was okay to post a similar one.  The class doesn't go over proper indentation and brace placement.  I'll be sure to find that aspect so where.

Comment: I am taking the open online version on Edx.org